# `dig +trace` not work , while with no trace it works well

Tags: networking, dns

here is the log from APPLE M1 macOS12.5.1:

```
➜  ~ dig @192.168.1.1 e0327ad868d138f2.jijifun.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @192.168.1.1 e0327ad868d138f2.jijifun.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31920
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;e0327ad868d138f2.jijifun.com.  IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
e0327ad868d138f2.jijifun.com. 600 IN    CNAME   out.jijifun.com.
out.jijifun.com.    600 IN  A   71.131.222.122
out.jijifun.com.    600 IN  A   71.131.199.68
out.jijifun.com.    600 IN  A   120.233.94.195
out.jijifun.com.    600 IN  A   120.233.94.196

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 28 00:49:37 CST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 128



➜  ~ dig +trace @192.168.1.1 e0327ad868d138f2.jijifun.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> +trace @192.168.1.1 e0327ad868d138f2.jijifun.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: Perhaps because `192.168.1.1` has DNS access to the internet, but your system is blocked. When you trace, the source is trying to communicate with the external DNS servers, but your firewall is stopping those packets.

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to the DNS at 192.168.1.1 and the firewall rules. The system 192.168.1.1 should answer apropriate and DNS traffic to external servers should be allowed.

Comment: @Bib,How to know which network link was blocked, `192.168.1.1 ` to the root nameserver or tld server or anything else? BTW, if firewall exists ,how does dig with no trace work well?

Comment: @Leslie__Joe I told you why without `trace` it works, the firewall allows it. We have no idea on the topology or configuration of your network, so this is all an educated guess.